# External MySQL connection using XAMPP on Windows

Tags: php, mysql

I am using XAMPP on a Windows 7 machine locally.

I want my web server to be able to connect to MySQL to retrieve data.

I have tried adding `bind-address=0.0.0.0` in `my.ini` file and restarted MySQL service but i get an error when trying to connect saying:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP_ADDRESS' (110) in /home/user/public_html/admin/db_connection.php on line 21
```

connection string is: `$mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($mysqli));`

Comment: The IP address of the MySQL server you would like to connect is `IP_ADDRESS` as a string and that is the problem.

Comment: I have just replaced that so i do not share my IP Address

Comment: @MySQLRockstar i am running Windows

Comment: Check the privileges in mysql database tables whether the user is allowed to connect from specific host or any host (`%`) . Also ensure that MySQL port OPEN to public access

Comment: @MySQLRockstar where do i check this? I have checked the user table in the mysql database and the root user has host = %

Comment: @MySQLRockstar I have also created a new user that has full access to everything and the host is the IP Address of my web server that is connecting to the database

Comment: plsu there is a port open on the router that points to the machine running XAMPP

Comment: have you tried connecting from terminal `mysql -h 'remoteip' -u user -p`

Comment: @MySQLRockstar no cannot connect on there either. get the same error - ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP_ADDRESS' (110)

Comment: Check if firewall blocking anything

Comment: nope nothing being blocked. firewall is switched off currently

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check the following

1. As you said from terminal also you are getting the same error (Ignore this) Just to make sure that it is not the fault in php code credentials

   `mysql -h 'remoteip' -u user -p`
2. `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;`
3. In my.ini

   `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`
4. Ensure skip-networking is commented in my.ini

   `# skip-networking`
5. Lastly check firewall

Comment: Ok, I have checked all of these steps and all is looking okay. but i still cannot connect

Comment: Add `bind-address=0.0.0.0` just under mysqld